# Icons are skewed

Tags: windows-xp, icons

This happens on a Windows XP machine (SP3). The icons (and to some extent fonts) are skewed. They look blurry/distorted and slightly higher than normal.

[image]

Any idea what is causing this? And how to fix it? I've tried updating graphic card drivers etc.

Edit: updated screenshot with arrows pointing to examples of skewed icons.

Comment: Are you running in the native resolution of your monitor?

Comment: Can't find any weird looking icons in your screenshot. Can you tell us which icon makes problems?

Comment: @techie007 I am, yeah. Have tried across two monitors

Comment: @Ranon I've updated the screenshot to add some arrows pointing to examples of skewed icons

Comment: It looks like you've changed the font (or possibly the font size) from the default used in Windows XP. I seem to remember this would cause icons to be stretched inelegantly.

Comment: Better screenshot, now I can see the problem, too. But sorry, haven't got a clue whats wrong here.

Comment: @sblair That might be what it is. It's not my own computer, but i'm trying to tidy up my dads :) Any way to reset it to the default?

Comment: You might want to close out of bank websites when you take screen shots.

Comment: Hehe, I only noticed that a bit later. Its only the link to log in, which anyone can access

Answer (score 2):

In XP in | control pannel | display | Appearances tab | Advanced | a person could select and ODD size for ICON, and then icons would be resized , this could effect the systray icons and standard explorer icons. the "default" is 32, but an odd setting like say 37 could cause weird interpolations like that.

Also other odd size settings , in there have effected other things, like the height of the Title bars, and text sizes.

Other things might be some utility or something that is adjusting the size of those with some other zooming routine?  Of course a Theme could set that item, and a theme could retract it again , just when you thought it was fixed.

I do not think that setting an ODD DPI would effect that, but mabey? DPI would be in | Control pannel | Display | Settings Tab | Advanced | General Tab |

Because it is shown well on 2 icons , it could just be that the icons chosen for display are some sort of 16pix or 24pix icons instead of standard 32pixel icons.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I tried changing the font sizes, but many icons were still skewed. Changint the DPI setting back to 96 (from 120 or something like that) did the trick.